# How to convert a number range from 0-200 into 1-5 range

Tags: objective-c, math

I have a value from 0 to 200 where 0 is better quality and 200 the worst quality.

How could I convert (In obj-c/cocoa framework) that to an integer from 0-5 being 5 best?.

For example 200 would be 0  and 0 would be 5.

Comment: What would 199 become? And what would 1 become?

Comment: also, the title and text don't match ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully the rounding works here:

```
int input;
int output = 5 - (int)floorf( ((float)input)/40.0f);
```

You may get the same results by just doing

```
int output = 5 - (input/40);
```

but it depends on your compiler's math settings.

Answer (score 9):

In general case if you have to transform `Q = [A, B]` to `Q' = [A', B']`, where `f(A) = B'` and `f(B) = A'`, then an arbitrary `X` in space `[A, B]` will have for `[A', B']` the following value:

```
X' = X * k + d;
```

where

```
k = (B' - A') / (A - B);

d = A' - B * k;
```

So, for your case we have `A = 200`, `B = 0` and `A' = 5`, `B' = 1`, resulting:

```
k = -1/50

d = 5
```

an arbitrary value `x` from `[0, 200]` space will be translated as follow:

```
x' = x * (-1 / 50) + 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let x in 0..200. Do (200 - x) / 40 if you want a result between 0 and 5, or (200 - x) / 50 + 1 if you want something between 1 and 5.

Comment: I think it would be useful to post general map from [a;b] to [c;d]

Comment: @Konstantin Mikhaylov: already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794847/how-to-convert-a-number-range-from-0-200-into-1-5-range/4794895#4794895)

Answer (score 1):

I think should work where [0-200] is your quality score.
5 - ([0-200] / 40)

Answer (score 0):

Alexander C.'s suggestion of (200 - x) / 50 + 1 is mathematically correct if the output should be interpreted as the sampled point within the [1,5] interval.  With this formula, an output of 5 is only possible with an exact input of 0 (taken from [0,200]).

However, I expect that the original poster intends that each integer in [1,5] be representative of a subinterval of [0,200].  For example, that 5 corresponds with subinterval [0,39], and 4 with [40, 79] etc.  If this is the intention, Alexander C.'s solution is a mathematically correct solution for a slightly different problem, in which case Stephen Furlani's approach is preferred.